# Zabbix Performance (history syncer 100%)

Tags: proxy, mysql, mariadb, zabbix

Since November 2018 we have performance problems with Zabbix 3.4.10.
Since this time, we made tuning for tcp connections, tuning in the OS (CentOS 6.9), tuning in the MariaDB conf, tuning in the Zabbix Server conf and tuning in the Zabbix Proxies conf.

The following problem remains:

2 times a day (5:22 p.m. and 8:22 p.m., we have different hours in the past) History Syncer reaches 100% and proxies become "NoDataProcessing".
While history syncer is at 100% several "NoData" alarms start to appear.
To recover, we stop the 2 major proxies, restart the server and raise the 2 proxies with a time interval.

Number of hosts 6679
Number of items 732813
Number of triggers 358638
Required server performance, new values per second 2695.54

Hardwares (VM):

- Server:
  CPU: 4 CPU
  Memory: 24GB
- Database (Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.4-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1):
  CPU: 8 CPUs
  Memory: 64GB
  Disk: SSD

Infrastructure:

1 Zabbix Server version 3.4.10 (lx-all-mon-zserver-01)
1 Database Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.4-MariaDB (lx-all-mon-zdb-03)
6 proxies for machines
1 proxy for Databases monitoring
1 proxy for webchecks

[Logs, confs and graphs](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-mX2U8pYhc__AbUpHKJqU8suG2VjOcLc/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: 100% of what?  If CPU, then what queries were running at the time?  To get to the bottom of the problem, we probably need to look at it from a MySQL/MariaDB point of view.  Zabbix's output seems to be obfuscating the issue.  Do you know how to connect to the database from phpmyadmin or mysql workbench or the commandline tool 'mysql'?

Comment: With the caveat that I can't access any of the files in that SharePoint link (and so probably others cannot either): Zabbix should be monitoring itself. Check its own graphs to see if a bottleneck is obvious. And post the data in the question itself, so that it remains accessible even if external links are not.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

- My.cnf has been changed to the settings below:

```ini
[client-server]

[mysqld]
datadir = /opt/timwe/data/mysql
innodb_log_group_home_dir = /opt/timwe/data/mysql/innodblog
log-bin = /opt/timwe/data/mysql/binlog
log_error = /opt/timwe/log/mysql_error.log
slow_query_log_file = /opt/timwe/log/slow_query.log
tmpdir=/opt/timwe/data/mysql/tmpfs
innodb_autoextend_increment        = 256
innodb_buffer_pool_instances       = 12
innodb_buffer_pool_size            = 48G
innodb_concurrency_tickets         = 5000                                                 
innodb_file_per_table              = 1                                                   
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit     = 2  
innodb_flush_method                = O_DIRECT
innodb_log_file_size               = 512M
innodb_log_files_in_group          = 8
innodb_old_blocks_time             = 1000
innodb_open_files                  = 2048
innodb_stats_on_metadata           = OFF
innodb_force_recovery = 0
skip-name-resolve
bind-address                       = 0.0.0.0
default_storage_engine             = innodb
event_scheduler                    = ON
binlog-row-event-max-size          = 8192
binlog-format                      = MIXED
character_set_server               = utf8
collation_server                   = utf8_bin
expire_logs_days                   = 1
join_buffer_size                   = 262144
max_allowed_packet                 = 32M
max_connect_errors                 = 10000
max_connections                    = 5000
max_heap_table_size                = 134217728
port                               = 3306
query_cache_type                   = 1
query_cache_size                   = 268435456
slow-query-log                     = ON
table_open_cache                   = 2048
thread_cache_size                  = 512
tmp_table_size                     = 134217728
user                               = mysql
wait_timeout                       = 86400

[mysql_safe]
log-error=/opt/timwe/log/mysqld_safe_error.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Comment: Additional information request from your MariaDB 10.3.4 server. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
G) SELECT name, count FROM information_schema.innodb_metrics ORDER BY name; 
for server workload tuning analysis.

Comment: What are the geographic locations of your involved MariaDB host and the servers you are monitoring?  Country list (appx count of servers in each country) would be fine for basic info to get an idea of the scope of the effort.

Comment: Are you aware MariaDB 10.3.4 is a Beta version?  Beta versions are not intended to be run in production.  There have been many STABLE releases since.2018-01-18.  Consider using 10.3.12 released 2019-01-07 as STABLE.  It would have 6 months of 'traction' and you would not be considered to be an early adopter and need to find and report bugs.